# Media Picker filename search not accurate

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Is there a way to fix the search in a Media Picker component for Umbraco? I noticed that when I click on the Media Picker component and tried to search for the file I uploaded I ended up of getting all sort of results that has nothing to do with the search I've been looking for. So ideally I was hoping that if I type `image001.png` I was expecting to find all image with that name. But to my surprise when I do the search I get presented with files that is not even `image001.png`. See below image

[image]

As you can see I tried to search for 200 but I got presented with a file that has a name of `test.jpg`

Is there a way to fix this filter behavior? I'm using Umbraco 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Did test have 200 in the path where the media library stored it?  Search is a bit of a black art sometimes.  You can clear and re-build the indexes as that might help improve things.

I do not think there are any custom packages to improve this.  YOu could create your own custom search fairly quickly n the backend within a new tab, like this:
https://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-7-tutorials/umbraco-backend-customisation/how-to-display-an-mvc-view-in-the-umbraco-backend/

Then you can use examine to query media yourself and only search on the filename.  Prob not the most helpful answer but it is a option :)

Comment: How do I rebuild index in Umbraco?

Comment: go into the backend, settings, examine managements, clear the internal and external index.  you should see some buttons.  Other option is to delete the files in the App_Data folder 'App_Data' -> 'Temp' -> 'ExamineIndexes'

More info here: https://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-7-tutorials/umbraco-caching/how-to-refresh-the-umbraco-cache/